# Retrieve AccountUser List Using WS Proxy and returns no rows Found

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, wsproxy

Help, I'm new to using WS Proxy.
I'm trying to retrieve Inactive users but throws me no rows found.
Here's the code I used.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");

try {
  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var cols = ["Name","Email","CreatedDate","LastSuccessfulLogin","ActiveFlag","Roles"];
  
  Write("cols: " + Stringify(cols));
  
  var filter = {
    Property: "ActiveFlag",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: "False"
  };
  var desc = prox.retrieve("AccountUser", cols, filter);
  
   Write("desc.Results.length: " + desc.Results.length);
  
  Variable.SetValue("@desc", desc.Results);
} catch (e) {
  Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>

%%=v(@desc)=%%
```

Comment: It seems retrieving the AccountUser object always returns the result is an empty array now, although it did work in the past

Comment: That's sad to hear. I've used the SOAP API with the xml payload, I had a hard time parsing that, since 'BuildRowSetXML' cannot detect the nodes.

Comment: Are you running it in the parent BU?  If not, I'd recommend that.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs you're right. needs to run in Parent BU